How to profile a training using ultralytics yolo?
I think I have an issue with the pre-processing phase of a training based on yolo, see here.
What is happening is that during the preparation of the dataset that is moved to the GPU RAM, the performance I have on the system I am using do not seem to be ok, approximately 40 it/s. I have to wait for one minute for the ~1100 images I have in my dataset which sounds like a lot to me.
I would like to perform a profiling to diagnose the problem and maybe adjust the settings of my training. However, I am struggling to profile the model training.
I was thinking about profiling with tensorboard with something like:
log_dir = './logs/runProfile'  
writer = SummaryWriter(log_dir)

# Define the profiling context
with profile(
    activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU, ProfilerActivity.CUDA],  # Track both CPU and GPU activity
    schedule=torch.profiler.schedule(wait=2, warmup=2, active=6),  # Configure profiling schedule
    on_trace_ready=tensorboard_trace_handler(pathProf),  # Save logs for TensorBoard
    record_shapes=True,  # Record the shapes of input tensors
    profile_memory=True,  # Track memory usage
    with_stack=True,  # Include the stack trace
) as prof:

   model.train(
        data=datapath, exist_ok=False, epochs=1, device=[0], patience=100, imgsz=1344,
        cache='ram', batch=16, verbose=True, workers=32, profile=False
    )

writer.close()

but that does not work (no profiling whatsoever can be seen in the tensorboard dashboard that I get). Has someone successfully profiled a training with this framework to gain some insight on the CPU/GPU usage and such?
Thanks in advance!
